# Changing binding environment for function in R?

Tags: r

[Wickham_Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) mentioned using `pryr::where()` to find the environment where the name is defined. For instance:

```
where("sd") 
#> <environment: package:stats
```

But if I change the binding environment:

```
e <- new.env() 
e$g <- function () 1 
where("g") 
# Can't find g
```

It seems that  `pryr::where()` doesn't work for new defined environment. What is the reason? Something I'm missing?

Comment: The object needs to be on your search path in order for `where()` to find it. Running `search()` tells you what's on your search path. You'd have to attach `e` in order to see it.

Comment: @MrFlick  It makes sense. I'm thinking if where() can locate any object in any environment, then it would be amazing. For instance, if I forgot the new environment I defined before, now I want to use where() to help me find it. Additionally, "g" shown in above cannot be attached after binding it to a new environment `attach(g)  # object 'g' not found`

Comment: You need to attach the environment `e` not the function `g` but generally attach is considered a bad practice. Better to create a package at that point. Environments exist to isolate objects so searching them all by default isn't a great idea. You could write a function to iterate all the environments to find objects I suppose. But probably better not to lose your function in the first place.

Comment: @MrFlick  `attach' only works for lists, data frames and environments`. You're correct.

Comment: @MrFlick I try to modify `where()` function to see can I make it iterate all environments to find my object.